# exit default text based browser launched by ipython notebook

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

If you run `ipython notebook` on a headless machine, by default it launches a text based browser (at least on Ubuntu).

It is not at all clear how to quit from this browser. What keystrokes are needed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is answered by a [similar question on ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707339/how-to-exit-default-www-browser/707344#707344).

Basically, on Ubuntu, ipython/jupyter launches launches the generic `www-browser`, a generic name for a CLI browser to point to, which is managed by Debian alternatives system. [Follow the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707339/how-to-exit-default-www-browser/707344#707344) to see how to exit it.